# MySQL "create trigger tr_emp before insert or update"

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
delimiter //
create trigger tr_emp2 before insert or update
on employee for each row
begin
  if new.ID<>10100 then
      if new.Mgr not in (select ID from employee)
      then
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid Mgr_id!';
      end if;
  end if;
end;//
delimiter ;
```

How to express "create trigger tr_emp before insert or update" ,is it a wrong exoression ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two triggers, but you can move the common code into a procedure and have them both call the procedure.